# R cannot be resolved into a variable when integrating two packages

Tags: android, src

i try to integrate Twitter project to Facebook project by copying and paste all the relevant files and clean the integration project. However, in the GEN file(R.java and BuildConfig.java)  the twitter packages is deleted. it seems like the GEN file can only be generated for one packages in SRC.

Comment: try fix properties OR Clean Project OR restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, there is just one R file.  You have several options though.  You probably could leave the Twitter and Facebook in their individual projects (instead of copying them into your project), and add them via the Android Library system. Or, you would need to copy all the class files, plus all the resource files and any other required files.  (I expect that the resource files weren't copied, and thus not included in the project R file).

Personally, I'd recommend the first method.  Just add each project (Twitter and Facebook) to Eclipse.  Then right-click and select Properties.  Choose the Android section, and in the lower half of the panel, check "Is Library".  In your project, right-click on it and select Properties, then Android.  In the lower half, (same location as the "Is Library") select Add and add your Twitter and Facebook projects.  That should include them in the build for your project, including any R files they might have!

Update (Activities in Library projects):

Check the "Declaring library components in the manifest file" section of the [Library section](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html).  Essentially, you'll need to declare all the Activities, etc, in YOUR project's manifest.  You'd still link the libraries as described.  (There's also a more detailed explanation of how to configure the libraries at that link as well!)

Comment: since they are different project folder then they cant run each other's activities? i've got facebook activities and twitter activities to auto switch at interval.